# C# Continuous Ping

Tags: c#, ping

I'm trying to build a continuous ping program that's really used for our LAN in troubleshooting. However, I'm having a little difficulty with the implementation.

The code actually does the pain correctly. True starts the continuous paying but, false does not stop it. It continues to loop indefinitely. I tried a few configurations with other loops, with no success.

I'm not really seeing what I'm doing wrong and I was hoping that I could get some assistance.

Would really appreciate some help.

Thank you in advance.

```
using System.Threading;

    private void btnContinuousPing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task StillLost = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            bool boCheckbox = cbContinuousPing.Checked;
            while (boCheckbox == true)
            {
                PingStuff();
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                if (boCheckbox == false) // Redundant
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    void PingStuff()
    {
        // Trying to build continuous ping.
        // ISSUE: While loop infinitely.
        // Setting the "cbContinuousPing.Checked" to false
        // doesn't stop the loop.
        Ping pingSender = new Ping();
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions();
        // Fragmentation behavior.
        options.DontFragment = true;
        // Set TTL to 48.
        options.Ttl = 48;
        // Create Empty buffer.
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
        // Wait x seconds for a reply.
        int timeout = 4000;
        // Ping device.
        PingReply reply = pingSender.Send("192.168.1.1", timeout, buffer, options);
        // Display Results.
        Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            txtContinuousPing.AppendText(string.Format("Address: {0}, byte={1}, time={2}, TTL={3}, Don't fragment: {4}", 
            reply.Address.ToString(), reply.Buffer.Length, reply.RoundtripTime, options.Ttl, options.DontFragment) + Environment.NewLine);
        }));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this line:

```
bool boCheckbox = cbContinuousPing.Checked;
```

inside your while loop.

Comment: Thank you so much Phil for your help. You know, it's kind of funny. Right after I posted I noticed that the bool wasn't in the loop. :-) Once I placed it within the while statement it started working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're caching the value of `boCheckbox` once, outside the while loop, and then inside the loop the code continually examines the value but never updates it.

Instead, you might consider using the actual value (rather than a cached value) for the `while` condition. Also, you also don't need the redundant check inside the loop:

```
private void btnContinuousPing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task StillLost = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (cbContinuousPing.Checked)
        {
            PingStuff();
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    });
}
```